# how to mock method called by MockedConstruction Object

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, mockito, junit5

I have new instance which will be mocked.
I am using `MockedConstruction` for `junit5` for that;
`GitLabApi gitlabApi = new GitLabApi("", ""))`

it has two methos

1. `MergeRequestApi mr = gitlabApi.getMergeRequestApi();`
2. `mergeRequest = gitlabApi.getMergeRequestApi().getMergeRequest("", (long) 1);`

method1 is run as expected but for method2 its throwing `Could not initialize mocked construction`

following are test case

```
    try(MockedConstruction ruleModelMapper = Mockito.mockConstruction(GitLabApi.class, (mock, context) -> {
        Mockito.when(mock.getMergeRequestApi()).thenReturn(m);
        Mockito.when(m.getMergeRequest(anyString(), anyLong())).thenReturn(mr);
    })){
```

Comment: try changing the second one to - mock.getMergeRequestApi().getMergeRequest(anyString(), anyLong())